# How to round up a decimal?

Tags: php, math, rounding

How can I use `round()` to round a number to the superior number as soon as there is a decimal?

For example:

```
1.00001      = 2
1.1          = 2
1.4785834975 = 2
1.00         = 1
1.99         = 2
3.01         = 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is called [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

```
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**This might be helpful for you:**

`floor()` will go down.

`ceil()` will go up.

`round()` will go to nearest by default.

```
<?php
echo ceil(3.4);    // 4
echo ceil(8.89);  // 9
?>
```

Comment: The way its put together might confuse the OP